# PG::FeatureNotSupported: ERROR: FOR UPDATE is not allowed with aggregate functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm getting a PG error and I can't figure out how to rewrite this statement is a way that works.  When I run it in the rails console, everything seems to be fine.  But when I try to process it as a background job, it borks with the following error:

```
    /Users/lorenzsell/DEV/Heartbeat-pods/app/mailers/notifications_mailer.rb:44:in `community_update'
/Users/lorenzsell/DEV/Heartbeat-pods/app/jobs/send_community_digest_job.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
/Users/lorenzsell/DEV/Heartbeat-pods/app/jobs/send_community_digest_job.rb:16:in `block in perform'
/Users/lorenzsell/DEV/Heartbeat-pods/app/jobs/send_community_digest_job.rb:8:in `perform'
/Users/lorenzsell/DEV/Heartbeat-pods/app/jobs/schedule_send_community_digest_job.rb:9:in `block in perform'
/Users/lorenzsell/DEV/Heartbeat-pods/app/jobs/schedule_send_community_digest_job.rb:8:in `each'
/Users/lorenzsell/DEV/Heartbeat-pods/app/jobs/schedule_send_community_digest_job.rb:8:in `perform'
/Users/lorenzsell/DEV/Heartbeat-pods/lib/tasks/email_tasks.rake:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
-e:1:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::FeatureNotSupported: ERROR:  FOR UPDATE is not allowed with aggregate functions
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."receiver_id" = $1 AND "activities"."is_read" = 'f' FOR UPDATE
/Users/lorenzsell/DEV/Heartbeat-pods/app/mailers/notifications_mailer.rb:44:in `community_update'
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
community_ids = Activity.where(receiver_type: "community", is_read: false).uniq.pluck(:receiver_id)
```

Comment: I don't see how that snippet could produce that SQL. Are you sure it's not coming from another line of the code? Something with `.count`?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure.  I've updated the error snippet with the rest of the message.  Based on my analysis, I've traced it to that line which is on: /schedule_send_community_digest_job.rb:8:in `perform'.  Do you think it's something else?

Comment: Maybe post the source of the `community_update` method from `notifications_mailer`?

Comment: It looks like the issue is coming from this line:   mail(to: subscriber.email, from: from, subject: "There are #{notifications.count} new pods in #{@community.name}").  Notifications comes from this line: notifications = Activity.where(receiver_id: options['id'], is_read: false).lock(true).  Is there a reason I can't call ".count" on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html), `lock` causes ActiveRecord to generate a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`. Postgres won't let you perform a count on such queries (though other databases might--this is probably why it works in the console), so you need to call `count` on your `Activity` relation *before* you call `lock`.

```
# base query
notifications = Activity.where(receiver_id: options['id'], is_read: false)

# save count
notifications_count = notifications.count

# apply lock
notifications = notifications.lock(true)
```